# Attaching unique id to endpoint(Web Push Notification)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, push-notification

I am working on implementing WebPush notification. When the user enables the notification, the json is generated with following data(Endpoint,auth,p256dh). At this point everything works fine and i am receiving the notification. But the problem is when i am reloading the page, the service worker is updated and a new json is generated with the above said data. The recently generated data is also inserted to the database resulting two entries for one browser device. What i want is a way to update the first inserted entry in database based on some unique id.

Comment: What have you tried? *I want [...]*, I want a lof of stuff as well but no one has ever achieved anything in life without putting some effort in it. Once you have done something and you are stuck come back to us so we can help you out then. :-)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site.  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: @Guthardt; On what basis you said i came here for help without doing any stuff.